# How to make a shopping cart using nodejs and mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am building a ecommerce website with nodejs and mysql. I have user registration and login and products page with CRUD, but what is the best way to modify the cart?

I have tried to insert data from the products table into another table called cart but nothing happened when I attempted.

Comment: Please show what you are attempting, and we may be able to identify where you are having trouble. The question, as it is, is too broad.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question is far too vague for anyone to offer any meaningful help.  Edit you question and add your code.  Do some Google searches for examples of cart setups in Node. Try to narrow this down to a specific question or problem you're encountering

Answer (score 0):

Here is some of what I have already: I have products page and information stored in MySQL database which is hosted on gearhost. I have user login pages too. I just want to know how I can add the products to a cart and how to make the cart page, remove from cart, to checkout and etc.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.render("index");
console.log("Home page")
console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies);
});

app.get('/products',function(req, res){ 
let sql = 'SELECT * FROM item'
let query = db.query(sql, (err, res1) => {
if(err) throw err;
console.log(res1);

res.render('products', {res1});
});

console.log("Now you are on the products page!");
});

app.get('/newproduct',function(req,res){
res.render('newproduct')

}); 
app.post('/newproduct',function(req,res){

let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile
var filename = sampleFile.name;
sampleFile.mv('./images/'+ filename, function(err){
});

let sql = 'INSERT INTO item (title, brand, image,genre,description,quality,price)
VALUES ("'+req.body.title+'", "'+req.body.brand+'",   
   "'+filename+'","'+req.body.genre+'","'+req.body.description+'","'+req.body.quality+'",   '+req.body.price+')'
let query = db.query(sql,(err,res) =>{
if(err) throw err;
});
res.redirect("/products");

});
```